# Wordpress archive posts returns user to homepage

Tags: permalinks, archives

I am trying to add archives to a sidebar in my wordpress blog. I use: `<?php wp_get_archives('cat=1'); ?>` to get display the archives. I now see on the screen the past few months when I have posted content however when I click on the month to see those posts it just takes me back to the homepage instead of pulling up the posts. If someone could explain why this is happening and how to solve it that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

are you using archives widget?
if not then which function you are calling to get archives.

try to add this code (below) in your sidebar.

```
<?php $archives = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=10&echo=0');
if ($archives) { ?>
  <ul class="archive-list">
     <?php echo $archives; ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

this will output as an unordered list of last 10 monthly archives, you can change limit and type to weekly or as needed.

for more information about wp_get_archives found on codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Comment: I am quite confused. I just want in my sidebar on my blog page an archives for cat with id=1. When the archive is clicked it will take me to a page with the posts from cat=1 for that month. I have a sidebar php file and I registered the sidebar in my functions.

Comment: i think you are trying to display posts by category 1, for this wp_get_archives(); is not appropriate function because cat is not a valid pram, if this is the case then you need to use wp_query or get_posts for the category 1.

Comment: i want to be able to get the posts from cat=1 by month

Comment: are you want to display months links in the sidebar and then click on month link want to display posts by this month from cat 1?

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion.(isn't that how an archive works?)

Comment: copy the index.php to date.php and customize it, run a new wp query to display posts from cat=1

Comment: i put it in archives and it works using type=monthly&limit=10&echo=0 except when I add &cat=1 it doesn't apply the filter: <?php $archives = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=-1&echo=0&cat=1');

Comment: cat is not a valid pram for wp_get_archives(); see the codex [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Comment: so how do I just get a specific category???

Comment: found a solution for your problem [here](http://kwebble.com/blog/2007_08_15/archives_for_a_category)

Comment: That plugin is 4 years old i already saw that one

Comment: 4 years old is not a reason if it is working properly

Comment: i searched for it and it didn't come up

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you don't have an archive.php. Without this, WP will default to index.php.

See the [template hierarchy in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview).

Maybe grab an archive.php from a standard theme (such as twentythirteen) and go from there.

Comment: i copied my page.php into my archive.php

Comment: That was an unusual move.

Comment: can u please explain setting up archives

Comment: As I said, you can copy archive.php from a standard theme. Although, I assume you are using an off-the-shelf theme, so you should try and replace the archive.php you overwrote.

Comment: my theme is completely custom